# How to specialize a class template with a template?

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

Consider the class template:

```
template<typename T>
struct A
{
  T data;

  static const bool flag;
  static bool calc_flag()
  {
    // Default value;
    return false;
  }
};

template<typename T>
const bool A<T>::flag = A<T>::calc_flag();
```

And now I'd like to specialize this template for the following class template:

```
template<char N>
struct B
{
  static const bool is_a;
};

template<char N>
const bool B<N>::is_a = N == 'a';
```

in order to the `A<B<N>>::flag` will be initialized with the `B<N>::is_a`. I.e., I'd like to specialize the `calc_flag()` method for such the case. How could this be done?

Answer (score 1):

You could separate the calculation to an implementation `struct` and only specialize that

```
template<class T>
struct calc_flag_impl {
    static bool calc_flag() { return false; }
};

template<typename T>
struct A
{
  T data;

  static const bool flag = calc_flag_impl<T>::calc_flag();
};
```

Now you can specialize `calc_flag_impl`

```
template<char N>
struct calc_flag_impl<B<N>> {
    static bool calc_flag() { return B<N>::is_a; }
};
```

Note: The specialization must exist prior to instantiation of the class template for your type for it to work with static class variables.

Comment: ["When writing a specialization, be careful about its location; or to make it compile will be such a trial as to kindle its self-immolation"](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/temp.expl.spec#8.sentence-2) ([\[temp.point\]/7](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/temp.point#7) highlights the danger here).

Comment: Thank you for the reply, it's interesting. But I'd like to know how to specialize one template with another, when the second one is parametrized with non-type parameter(s). Because I faced with issues on this way...

Comment: You can specialize exactly the way I have done here. Click [here](https://godbolt.org/z/nhz858aTE) to see it live. I had to either initialize `flag` out-of-line or make `calc_flag` `constexpr` to make it compile as expected.